# How to detect scroll wheel down on windows c++?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to detect scrollwheel events in c++ on windows, but having trouble.

I've tried various ways to detect mousewheel events into `wParam`, using `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM`, `HIWORD`, and `GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM` (which gave me a syntax error). Not sure what to try from here. I'm guessing I am using the relevant methods wrong, or I am not preparing them correctly.

```
int isScrollDown() {
    WPARAM wParam;
    GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
    std::cout << wParam << std::endl;
}

//inside main()
while(1) {
    if(isScrollDown()) {
        //do something
        break;
    }
    sleep(50);
}
```

It prints 6422352 regardless of whether I am doing something with my mouse or not.

Comment: You're supposed to give a value you got from an event (WndProc) to `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM`.

Comment: Like the [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) event...

Comment: Okay, how would I go about capturing that event?

Comment: To capture this kind of events in a win32 application you are supposed to set up a window and an event loop... You _can_ get away with the console APIs for some limited stuff, but it's quite limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) message in [LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( *In* HWND   hwnd, *In* UINT   uMsg, *In* WPARAM wParam, *In* LPARAM lParam );](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633573) callback.

Then use the [GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646254(VS.85).aspx) Macro on the wParam, a positive indicate the wheel is rotated away from the user (up) and a negative indicates a rotation towards the user (down)